# Should a function implementer or function caller handle immutability

Tags: javascript, immutability, dependency-inversion

I know there is no right and wrong answer here, I'm just looking for other opinions on who should handle <strike>immutability</strike>, dependency inversion and decoupling.

**Example 1:** Here each function caller has the responsibility to pass a new object, let the function handle the changes and then return the response. The function implementer doesn't care about anything else other than the function contents.

```
function doSomething (something) {
  something.param = 1 // user input

  return {
    data: something
  }
}

// Caller 1
const response = doSomething(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))

// Caller 2
const response = doSomething(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))
```

**Example 2:** Here the function implementer has the responsibility to clone the new object, do the changes and then return the response.

```
function doSomething (something) {
  const tmpSomething = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(something))

  tmpSomething.param = 1 // user input

  return {
    data: tmpSomething
  }
}

// Caller 1
const response = doSomething(data)

// Caller 2
const response = doSomething(data)
```

Comment: Your first example isn't using immutability as you are modifying `something`. So since only example 2 achieves immutability (ignoring the fact that `tmpSomething` is mutated before being returned), then that has to be the answer to your question.

Comment: In the #1 the function also modifies a new object

Comment: The function modifies the object passed to it in #1. The only way you can claim "function also modifies a new object" is if you only ever pass it a new object. That is not, in any way, immutability. Sorry.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the "question" do the callers always pass a new object or the function creates the new object

Comment: Then you need to update your question to clarify this as this has nothing to do with immutability and everything to do with dependency inversion and decoupling.

Comment: In example 1 there's no need for the editSomething function to return a value. The value is reference to an object, and it's the same reference that was passed in. The caller already has a copy of that reference. It just needs to give it a name. Calling the function like this will make it clear to someone reading the code that editSomething mutates the object :


`const newSomething = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
editSomething(newSomething);`

Comment: surely neither. The object itself should be immutable or not.

Comment: @DavidArno you are right, it wasn't clear. I've updated the code snippets

Comment: Could the downvoters explain the reason for that? This is not StackOverflow, it's for SoftwareEngineering related questions.

Answer (score 4):

if you return an object of `MyType`, I (personally) would expect it to be a new object

I guess it's because I would expect to modify the parameter by using a ref call.

Also it would look weird:

```
var obj = new MyType();
var modifiedobj = EditSomething(obj);
```

If i see this code, i do not expect `obj` and `modifiedObj` to be the same, that's just confusing.

Comment: @DavidArno thx, I missed that. I've tried to adapt my answer to work for javascript. Though this question is not necessarily tied to a specific language.

Comment: You are right it isn't necessarily for javascript, it could apply to any other by ref language.

Comment: it might be confusing, but it's not uncommon